# Run script when dialog is hidden

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new in Chrome extensions development and I'm curious how to make extension to run even if dialog window is not "clicked". Right now my extension run only if I click icon and leave dialog displayed. As soon as I click to something else on page extension window hide and script stop executing. This is my code.

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>activity</title></head>  
<body style="width:300px;">  
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function injectTheScript() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    })
}
 setInterval(function(){   injectTheScript();    },2000);
```

**content_script.js**

```
function clickPlanet() {
    var planets = document.getElementsByClassName("collectbtn"),
        randomplanet = Math.floor(Math.random() * planets.length),
        clickplanet = planets[randomplanet];
    clickplanet.click();  
}  
clickPlanet();
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Such Activity",  
    "description": "Wow",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "background"],  

    "browser_action": { 
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icons/19.png",
            "38": "images/icons/38.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    },

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
    },

    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icons/16.png",
        "19": "images/icons/19.png",
        "38": "images/icons/38.png",
        "64": "images/icons/64.png",
        "128": "images/icons/128.png"
    }
  }
```

Comment: A popup script is only active while the popup is open.  If you want it to keep going, you'll need to use a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (which should become an event page, once you've worked out the bugs).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to display the popup without user interraction.
It was implemented this way to pevent extensions by themselves to display the popup, to avoid abusing with popups.

An alternative, if you really need to display something programatically, is to use the browser icon to display an iframe in the web page, with the same html and scripts as the popup.